# Selenium web driver, C#

Tags: selenium, element

I am new to selenium and web driver.My question is pretty straight forward. Sorry if you find this question of very basic level.
I am using Visual studio 2010 ultimate with selenium 2 and using language C# with browser IE 9.I tried to execute the below simple code.

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"D:\IEDriverServer\");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");


System.Console.WriteLine("Page title is: " + driver.Title);

Console.WriteLine(driver.Title);
Console.WriteLine("Waiting to find element");

IWebElement returnedValue = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));

Console.WriteLine("Element Found");
```

Above code throws the `Unable to find the element with name==...`
I thought that it might the browser loading issue. Browser doesnt get fully loaded hence causing it to show the error. Then i added the below code after driver.navigate line to make it wait till the browser fully loads.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TitleIs("Google"));
```

Strange thing is that it again ignores this webdriverwait line and jumps directly to "`wait.until`" line resulting in displaying the element not found error. What should i do. am i missing something here??

Comment: I don't use c# for selenium but shouldn't it be `driver.FindElementByName("q")` that's how it is in python.

Comment: does the google site get loaded?

Answer (score 2):

you are almost right in defining the wait ...but in C# there is different way to  enable Webdriver wait till the element is visible till page is loaded.

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
        {
            return d.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
        });
```

Hope this helps...All the best buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting an implicit wait with `driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));`.

According to the [Selenium documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html) this is by default 0 - that is, if the element is not found immediately, Selenium throws the "Unable to find the element with..." error.

Answer (score 0):

Change `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TitleIs("Google"));`

to `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("q")))`

There may be the case that the title of the page had been changed to google but the complete page was not loaded completely